# Montando relatorio com ReportViewer em C#

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Tenho duas tabelas do banco de dados que são a Compra e os Itens da Compra.
Como é possível fazer um relatório usando ReportViewer .rdlc que fique com o seguinte padrão:

```
Dados da Compra    
   Dados itens da Compra         
   Dados itens da Compra 
Dados da Compra    
   Dados itens da Compra
```

Sem a utilização de uma Table, utilizando um list, porque as varias informações não ficariam corretas em uma table.

Estou tentando enviar dois DataTable para o Relatorio, contento os dados da compra e os itens da compra, até então eu conseguir. Mas como faço para sincronizar os dados e gerar essa lista, falando que aqueles itens da compra pertence aquela compra.

A chave de ligação de ambas tabelas são:
Compra-
com_codigo;
ItensCompra-
com_codigo;

Comment: Relacionado:http://www.macoratti.net/08/03/vbn5_rpv.htm

Comment: Leia: http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2016/03/02/gerando-relatorios-do-report-viewer-com-entity-framework/

Comment: Leia: http://www.theclub.com.br/restrito/revistas/201302/aspn1302.aspx